# DIV Horizontal Scroll

Tags: html, css

I have several HTML elements inside a div with a fix width. The sum of the width of the inner elements is greater than the width of the container. How can I make the inner elements appear inline (and showing a horizontal scroll) instead of breaking after reaching the parent's width?

I could add a wrapper and assign it a min-width, but I want something that will change its size if the contents change.

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="contents" id="one"></div>
    <div class="contents" id="two"></div>
    <div class="contents" id="three"></div>
    <div class="contents" id="four"></div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
}

.contents {
    width: 35px;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
}
#one {
    background-color:#ABC;
}
#two {
    background-color:#333;
}
#three {
    background-color:#888;
}
#four {
    background-color:#AAA;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/elohr/G5YZ6/2/

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`, and add `white-space:nowrap;` to the container. If needed, add `white-space:normal` to the content elements. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G5YZ6/3/)

Comment: Thanks. I tried the display:inline-block, but I was missing the white-space:nowrap.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

1. Replace `float: left` with `display: inline-block;`
2. Use `white-space: nowrap;` to the container.

CSS:

```
#container {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #CCC;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.contents {
    width: 35px;
    height: 60px;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/praveenscience/G5YZ6/6/

Answer (score 0):

In your root DIV element you could always specify that overflow is scrollable:

```
<div id="container" style="overflow: scroll;">
  <div class="contents" id="one"></div>
  <div class="contents" id="two"></div>
  <div class="contents" id="three"></div>
  <div class="contents" id="four"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The OP already has `overflow: scroll`. Also it is not a good idea to have inline styles.

Comment: @Praveen -I see overflow set to auto not SCROLL. So its kind of weird! if you can see scroll.